# If - else in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I can get the alert to show, but it has some problems:

1. The title does not appear
2. I can't get the if statement part to work. The alert pops up showing only:

   > the message numbers must be 24 or less

   along with the close button and never changes.

Using XCode 6.3 and iOS 8.

```
var title: String!

if difference > hoursLabel {
    title = "Sorry!"
}
else if difference < hoursLabel {
    title = "That's better!"
}

let message =  "Number must be 24 or less"
var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .Default, handler: nil))

self .presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Try changing that `else if` to an `else`.

Comment: Whats difference and hoursLabel? Are those strings? Also it seems neither if statements are met. You can as suggested change the else if to else and that would at least trigger the second part. But it won't be the right if statement if your actual conditions are not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you provided, it seems that the problem is using `else if`, rather than `else` only

**Solution 1:**

```
var title: String!

if difference > hoursLabel {
    title = "Sorry!"
}
else {
    title = "That's better!"
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
let title = (difference > hoursLabel) ? "Sorry": "That's better!" ;
```